# Want to get video times from page

Tags: python, scrapy

I am doing a Coursera course for work. I need to log the times of each of the videos I am watching. I found scrapy and am excited. I logged into my course and have finished watching all the videos for that section.

I tried opening a scrapy shell: scrapy shell "https://class.coursera.org/regmods-030/lecture"

Then I opened up the page in a new tab with Firebug to try and find the HTML tags that had the times. I found: `<a blah > title (1:23) </a>` and 
`<div class="hidden"> Title (1:23)`.

In the shell after I opened the URL, I tried `response.xpath('//div[@class="hidden"]')` and got nothing.

Here is the spider code:

```
import scrapy

class DataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "data"
allowed_domains = ["coursera.org"]
start_urls = [
   "https://class.coursera.org/regmods-030/lecture"
]

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
        item = DataItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        item['desc'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
        yield item`
```

I realize that the above code is for the tutorial, but I cannot find how to search for the div.

Ultimately, what I want to do, is to be able to scrape the times of the videos to a CSV file, so I can then add them up. Then I can submit that info to my boss.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Well, did you implement the login functionality? Because you can access Coursera's classes when you are logged in. And Scrapy is not logged in when you just open the site. So you cannot find the `div` either.

Comment: Good point. And you can see my newbieness showing. Let me go back into the Scrapy docs and find out how to implement a login and then navigate to the page I need. I had logged in via FF and used that URL. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @Ghajba: I can't seem to find info in the Scrapy docs regarding using email as a login. Just formdata, which might not work with this code: <input type="email" data-reactid=".24vgnulcu0w.0.0.0.0.2.0.1.0.2.0.0.1" placeholder="Email" name="email" required="" tabindex="10006"> Any thoughts on where I can find examples or other docs? I tried searching scrapy, email, login.

Comment: Any thoughts as to what I need to do and where I can find docs for this?